# How to use an "or" inside a filter

Tags: python, django, filter, view

I want to make a search, but I need to bring the registers that have status Canceled or modified.

I thought that this would work but It didn't

```
citasotras = citas_agendarcita.objects.filter(cita_agendar_status="Modificada" or "",citas_tipodepaciente="mediexcel")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, The expression `"Modificada" or ""` evaluates to `"Modificada"`.

```
>>> "Modificada" or ""
'Modificada'
```

Therefore, your example is as if you simply had:

```
citasotras = citas_agendarcita.objects.filter(cita_agendar_status="Modificada", citas_tipodepaciente="mediexcel")
```

You want any objects where the `cita_agendar_status` is equal to any of the items in the list `["Modificada", ""]`. You can use `__in` to do this:

```
citasotras = citas_agendarcita.objects.filter(cita_agendar_status__in=["Modificada", ""] ,citas_tipodepaciente="mediexcel")
```

See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#in) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

For AND/OR conditions [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) can be used:

```
citas_agendarcita.objects.filter(Q(cita_agendar_status="Modificada")|Q(cita_agendar_status=""), \                               
                                 citas_tipodepaciente="mediexcel")
```

Comment: The `Q` object approach is useful for when you need to or together constraints on different fields, but I think the `__in` syntax for `cita_agendar_status` is clearer. And your two `Q` objects for `citas_tipodepaciente` are identical, unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I agree `__in` is the better option here. BTW Fixed `citas_tipodepaciente` thing, misread the OP's code actually.